# Should I select only the last child product category?

Tags: categories

When I select a product category, I am not sure if I should also check the parent categories' checkboxes too.

[image]

If I select parent categories too, then on category page under each product the displayed category is the top-parent instead of bottom-child category.

Answer (score 0):

you need to select the category where you want to show the product. if you are selecting parent category then product will show on parent page.
and if you are selecting child category product will only show in child pages of shop.

What you need to do here select both parent and child category , so product will show in parent page with number of count and child page of shop too.

Comment: But if I set the category page Display Style to "Both" (Subcategories and Products), I see products from the subcategories already (without specifically setting the category of these productst to also have parent category). Example: We have categories A with subcategory A1. Product P is in A1 (only in this category, checkbox for A not set). Now when I open category A page, I see A1 AND P.

Comment: are you using pagination or infinity scroll on the main category?

Comment: I did not set them specifically so I guess no.